# Set webbrowser identity

Tags: c#

When I navigate to some webpages they say update your browser. Obviously i am telling them i have an outdated browser or lack of a new one. I bypassed it and it ran normally in the browser anyways.

Is there anyway i can say i am an updated browser?

I dont know the proper name for it so i call it it's identity. If i could set it to be the latest version of chrome or internet explorer or the latest version of my own, that would be great.

If not, how can i do it with httpwebrequest?

Edit:
SUCCESS

By using http://www.whatismybrowser.com/what-is-my-user-agent
with chrome, I took that string and put it into my web browser. 
Obligatory success photo : http://postimg.org/image/5qx4s8opd/
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [`UserAgent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent(v=vs.110).aspx) string you should set.

Comment: How do you set  Webbrowser control's `UserAgent`? What value should OP set? In this form your post is only a comment not an answer.